# Angular Directives: How to control when chart is rendered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to set up an admin page. There are a bunch of elements, and when you click on one of them, a drop down appears with more information, specifically a high chart graph. Currently I'm using a directive to create the chart div, but I haven't been able to find a way to control when the directive is rendered, it happens automatically on page load.

Unfortunately, I have over 200 of these elements, and with the current set up of the page all 200 charts get rendered every time the page loads. Obviously, this leads to a bad user experience.

I am somewhat new to webdev in general. I'm not sure if I'm even approaching this problem in the right way. Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="source" ng-repeat="source in sources">
    ...
    <div source-dropdown-graph class="sources-dropdown-graph" ng-show="showDropdownGraph == source.myIndex" source="source"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using the ng-show to toggle the visibility of the graph when the user clicks. From the directive:

```
return {
    scope: {
        source: "=source"
    },
    templateUrl: 'source-dropdown-graph.html',
    link: link
};
```

The link function just renders the graph. And finally the html of the template:

```
<div id="chart-container" style="min-width: 70%; max-width: 1200px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Like I said, this is all working, except for rendering everything right off the bat. I thought of setting a flag in the `source` object of whether to render the chart or not, but I don't know how to get it to re-render when that value changes. Are directives even the right thing to use in this case? Like I said I'm still relatively new to web dev so I'm open to doing this completely differently. Thanks!

Comment: Simplest change would be to swap `ng-show` for `ng-if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using an `ng-if` instead of an `ng-show` to limit the amount of elements in the DOM, you can use a watch in your directive to watch the `source` for changes and control when to or when not to render.

```
return {
    scope: {
        source: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'source-dropdown-graph.html',
    link: link
};

function link (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('source', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        // condition(s) where you don't want to render
        // i.e. if the source is undefined or null
        if (!newValue || (newValue === oldValue)) {
            return;
        }

        // otherwise, render it every time source changes
        render();
    });

    function render () {
        // your rendering logic
    }
}
```